# Can opponents in ME3 be damaged by their own grenades?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Recently, I was trying to rescue two people in an elevator.

> The female Krogan and Mordin

This being Mass Effect, there were bad guys trying to stop me. One of them, in the course of trying to stop me, tossed a grenade into a wall, where it bounced off and landed at his feet (not his fault, he came down with a sudden case of shot-in-the-face-itis)

Unfortunately, so did I, and as a result I didn't get to see if he would be "hoist 'pon his own petard", as it were.

**Do opponents in ME3 take damage from their own grenades?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, enemies do not take friendly grenade damage. I just had a Husk grenade go off right next to a frozen solid Husk.

The grenade probably should have killed it, but it did absolutely no damage to it; the health bar was one bar down, just like it was when I froze the husk. The health bar didn't flash when the grenade when off either, which it does when enemies take damage.

Comment: Can confirm. Staggered a Cerberus trooper without killing him in the middle of his grenade throw. Grenade went up and landed right next to him before going off. No damage.

Answer (score 2):

Officially the answer is no, there is no friendly fire.  You cannot shoot your allies and the y cannot shoot you to affect health; if you are shot by your team mates you will suffer an accuracy penalty only.

With that said, it is possible for your allies to injure you and for you to harm them.  Both grenades and special shotgun abilities will cause friendly damage, which explain the comments about James' frag grenades.

Comment: Hmm, I've had friendly fire from friendly frag grenades. I had James throw a frag grenade at a baddie who was about to chop me with his sword. The grenade exploded infront of my face and I lost half my shield (but it worked, the guy I was fighting backed off)

Comment: I was actually asking about enemy friendly fire, not squad member friendly fire.